# array_walk not doing the walk for me

Tags: php, array-walk

When I pass an array as an extra argument to array walk, it does not get interpreted as I would expect.

```
function boom($item, $z )
{
    print_r("\n".$item);
    print_r("\n".$z);
}

$z=[ "alpha", "bravo" ];
$x=[ "one", "two" ];
array_walk( $x, 'boom', $z );
```

The output:

```
one
0 
two 
1
```

Why is zero and one printed?
Why don't I get alpha and bravo printed? How can I get alpha and bravo included in the output?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the manual, the second argument is the key and the third one will be your extra data

Comment: $z is my third argument...

Comment: I mean in your function boom

Comment: Ah! Well spotted... I have my php  man page open prior to raising the question but now I see what you suggest... let me try...

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that... Do you want to put that suggestion into an answer so I can give you the credit/points for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the code to pass $z as 3rd parameter like this:

```
function boom($item, $i, $z )
{
    print_r("\n".$item);
    print_r("\n".$z[$i]);
}

$z=[ "alpha", "bravo" ];
$x=[ "one", "two" ];
array_walk( $x, 'boom', $z );
```

You can find more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

> If the optional userdata parameter is supplied, it will be passed as
>   the third parameter to the callback.

Comment: You have to use $z[$i]. The third parameter passed to array_walk can be anything and does not need to be an array. So you do get the full parameter passed to the callback function.

Comment: @NineBerry fixed that. Thanks.